# Appium issue not able to select date

Tags: android, appium

I am trying to automate insurance related Android app, where I need to select policy effective date. However, I am not able to click on policy effective date I even tried all locators such as: id, name, classname, xpath.

The part below mentions all locators I used such as:

```
#id
clickeffectivee=ebroker.com.ebroker:id/edt_effective_date

#by name
clickeffectivee1=Policy Effective Date

#class name
clickeffectivee2=android.widget.EditText

#classname2
clickeffectivee3=TextInputLayout

#xpath with text
clickeffectivee4=//android.widget.EditText[@text="Policy Effective Date"]
clickeffectivee5=//android.widget.EditText[@name='Policy Effective Date']

#xpath with contain

clickeffectivee6=//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'effective_date_layout')]


#xpath with contain and text 

clickeffectivee7=//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'effective_date_layout')and (@text='Policy Effective Date')]
```

for this particular method as

```
    public void  selectdate () throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException, IOException,
    EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElementcp(appium.findElement(By.xpath(Lib.getProperty(CONFIG_PATH, "clickeffectivee7"))));
    cp.click();

        Thread.sleep(3000);
```

After running I am getting an error message I even tried so many times still I am getting the same below mentioned error message.

PFA image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPL1n.png).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you tried direct sendKeys to the date text field, many times it worked ? else you have to show the source of DateSelector inside app

Comment: HI @ Amit sendkeys is not working even i tried as move to mouse and then click , not able to click on data icon .